# How to avoid port in Downstream url in ocelot?

Tags: c#, heroku, ocelot

port is getting added at the Downstream url.  i want to access  a micro service hosted in heroku.  need to avoid port.
Please help.

Its working in local dev environment. But not working after deployment in Heroku.

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{catchAll}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "catalogapi-pinaki.herokuapp.com"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/cat-logApi/{catchAll}"

    }

  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "http://localhost"
  }
}
```

The Downstream Url  should be "https://catalogapi-pinaki.herokuapp.com/api/CatalogApi/GetAllItems".

Error:
message: Downstream url is https://catalogapi-pinaki.herokuapp.com:56084/api/CatalogApi/GetAllItems

[my Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC98i.png)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to force to the default port? You can specify the port using the port attribute inside "DownstreamHostAndPorts" like so:

```
     {
        "ReRoutes": [
            {
            "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{catchAll}",
            "DownstreamScheme": "https",
            "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
                {
                    "Host": "catalogapi-pinaki.herokuapp.com",
                    "Port": 443
                }
            ],
            "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/cat-logApi/{catchAll}"
            }
        ],
        "GlobalConfiguration": {
            "BaseUrl": "http://localhost"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We also faced same issue. we fixed issue using FIX 2.

**FIX 1:**
services.AddOcelot(Configuration.GetSection("OcelotSettings"))
                .AddDelegatingHandler(true);

Inside OcelotRerouteHandler you can replace your url and construct new httprequestmessage.
Refer : https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/delegatinghandlers.html

**Fix2:**

"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/subdomain/api/{catchAll}"

"Host": "catalogapi-pinaki.herokuapp.com",

If you have any subdomain , dont add it in HOST add in DownstreamPathTemplate.
For https port can be 443.